# Visual C# Display XML Web Browser

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt

So I am following a tutorial from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/18ca6734-ddb7-4f44-a77c-9a7713dcc2e1/how-to-view-xml-in-webbrowser-control-using-the-documenttext-property?forum=winforms). I have the following code but it simply won't display anything inside the web browser component. The specific instructions I followed are:

"Hi everyone,

I managed to do this using the following strategy:

1. *Download an HTML 1.0 compliant version of defaultss.xsl* (I'm using my own)
2. Create an XMLCompiledTransform object and load the "defaultss.xsl" stylesheet. I actually embedded it is a resource in my assembly and read it from there.
3. Transform your XML stream using the XMLCompiledTransform into an HTML stream.
4. Set the WebBrowser.DocumentStream = HTML stream

Remember to "AllowNavigation" otherwise the thing doesn't work.

Hope this helps,

B."

```
OpenFileDialog OpenCCD = new OpenFileDialog();
OpenFileDialog OpenXSL = new OpenFileDialog();
string xslpath, filepath;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenCCD.ShowDialog();
    filepath = OpenCCD.FileName;

}

private void cmd_XSL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenXSL.ShowDialog();
    xslpath = OpenXSL.FileName;
}

private void cmd_View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("XML Path:" + filepath + "\nXSL Path:" + xslpath);
    XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xsl.Load(xslpath);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    xsl.Transform(filepath, null, ms);
    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = ms;
}
```

The xml is pretty long so here is a piece of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif">
   <realmCode code="US"/>
   <typeId root="2.16.840" extension="PO"/>
   <templateId root="2.16"/>
   <templateId root="2.17"/>
   <id root="2.16.84" extension="E5"/>
   <code codeSystem="2.16.88" codeSystemName="" code="3" displayName="TITLE"/>
   <title>TITLE</title>
   <effectiveTime value="2925"/>
   <confidentialityCode code="Y" codeSystem=""/>
   <recordTarget>
      <patientRole>
         <id root="2.16.84" extension="215"/>
         <addr use="P">
            <streetAddressLine>123 GREEN TRAIL RD</streetAddressLine>
            <city>BIRMINGHAM</city>
            <state>AL</state>
            <postalCode>35211</postalCode>
            <country>USA</country>
         </addr>
         <telecom use="H" value="tel:000000000"/>
         <patient>
            <name>
               <given qualifier="L">ADAM</given>
               <family qualifier="R">EVERYMAN</family>
            </name>
            <ethnicGroupCode codeSystem="2.16.84" codeSystemName="Race" displayName="Not Hispanic or Latino"/>
            <languageCommunication>
               <languageCode code="eng"/>
            </languageCommunication>
         </patient>
      </patientRole>
   </recordTarget>

XSL is also long so here is a piece of it:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:n3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:n1="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:n2="urn:hl7-org:v3/meta/voc" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>

<xsl:variable name="tableWidth">50%</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="title">
    <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="/n1:CDocument/n1:title">
             <xsl:value-of select="/n1:CDocument/n1:title"/>
         </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>CDocument</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="n1:CDocument"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Have you verified that the XSL transformation works outside of this code? Please share your source XML and stylesheet.

Comment: Yes I have verified that it does work outside of this piece of code. I've updated my question to contain the resources you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was to use the following code instead. This code, saves a result.html and renders that inside the web browser control.

```
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(xslpath);
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);
myXslTrans.Transform(filepath, directoryPath+"result.html");
webBrowser1.Navigate(directoryPath+"result.html");
```